# How show coupons for each PRODUCT ID - Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hi I need create a shortcode to show a coupon lists for each product, example:

- PRODUCT ONE(127) -> have 3 coupons
- PRODUCT TWO(128) -> have 1 coupon

Render:
When the guest enter to see PRODUCT ONE
in the description I show with a SHORTCODE the 3 COUPONS.

I have this query, but I dont understand how pass the product id for filter it

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title AS coupon_code, wp_posts.post_excerpt AS coupon_description, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'product_ids'  AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'coupon_amount' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'free_shipping' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS free_shipping,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS expiry_date   
FROM wp_posts RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_coupon' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('discount_type','coupon_amount', 'product_ids')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid, wp_posts.post_title
```

AND SHOW ..

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqgRF.png

THE PRODUCT PAGE SHOW

[image]

MY CODE PHP IS

```
$sql = "SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title AS coupon_code, wp_posts.post_excerpt AS coupon_description, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'product_ids'  AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'coupon_amount' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'free_shipping' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS free_shipping,
  MAX(CASE WHEN wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'expiry_date' AND wp_posts.`ID` = wp_postmeta.`post_id` THEN wp_postmeta.`meta_value` END) AS expiry_date   
FROM wp_posts RIGHT JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'shop_coupon' 
  AND wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('discount_type','coupon_amount', 'product_ids')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_excerpt, wp_posts.post_name, wp_posts.guid, wp_posts.post_title";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Coupon</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Disccount</th>
    <th>Expire</th>
  </tr>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?= $row["coupon_code"];?></td>
    <td><?= $row["coupon_description"];?></td>
    <td><?= $row["coupon_amount"];?><?php if($row["discount_type"] == 'fixed'){echo'$';}?><?php if($row["discount_type"] == 'percent'){echo'%';}?>
    </td>
    <td><?= $row["expire_date"];?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php }}$conn->close();
?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Could you include the PHP code you've tried?

Comment: @BugHunterUK I edit the topic